# How to perform density-based clustering assessments of NetLogo turtles?

Tags: netlogo

I have the following code in netlogo 6.0.1 using the dbscan (density-based clustering) extension to measure clustering effects and cluster distribution attributes among turtles on the world interface.

```
extensions [ dbscan ]

to setup
  clear-all
  ask patches [ set pcolor white ]
  create-turtles 1000 [
    set color black
    set label-color blue
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]
  ask n-of 5 turtles [
    ask turtles in-radius 3 [
      set color one-of [red grey]
    ]
  ]
end

to-report radial-extent [ cluster ]
  report max map [
    a -> max map [
      b -> [
        distance a ] of b
    ]
    cluster
  ]
  cluster
end

to find-clusters
  let red-grey-turtles turtles with [ member? color [red grey] ]
  let clusters dbscan:cluster-by-location red-grey-turtles 3 3
  (foreach clusters range length clusters [ [c i] ->
    foreach c [
      t -> ask t [
        set label i
      ]
    ]
  ])
  let num-clust length clusters
  let max-clust-count max map length clusters
  let mean-clust-count mean map length clusters
  let var-clust-count variance map length clusters
  let stdev-clust-count standard-deviation map length clusters
  let max-clust-size mean map radial-extent clusters
  let mean-clust-size mean map radial-extent clusters
  let var-clust-size variance map radial-extent clusters
  let stdev-clust-size standard-deviation radial-extent clusters
end
```

However, when I run the code, I keep getting the following error:

`OF expected input to be an agent or agentset but got the list [(turtle 3) (turtle 19) (turtle 93) (turtle 186) (turtle 239) (turtle 243) (turtle 322) (turtle 326) (turtle 528) (turtle 587) (turtle 610) (turtle 712) (turtle 719) (turtle 736) (turtle 754) (turtle 799) (turtle 873) (turtle 874) (turtle 887) (turtle 889) (turtle 963) (turtle 18) (turtle 140) (turtle 156) (turtle 530) (turtle 557) (turtle 605) (turtle 687) (turtle 693) (turtle 919) (turtle 979) (turtle 252) (turtle 506) (turtle 978) (turtle 989) (turtle 14) (turtle 534) (turtle 586) (turtle 658) (turtle 133) (turtle 606) (turtle 702) (turtle 995) (turtle 597) (turtle 949) (turtle 160) (turtle 244) (turtle 703) (turtle 742) (turtle 902)] instead.`

Clearly the radial extent function is treating the turtle clusters as lists instead of agent sets due to the use of the `of`operator to determine out cluster radii.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good news: your reporter is OK ...

... just correct the last line

```
 let stdev-clust-size standard-deviation radial-extent clusters
```

to `map` the reporter over `clusters`:

```
 let stdev-clust-size standard-deviation map radial-extent clusters
```